# Looking for a Chrome extension to shorten urls

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There are certain sites that I visit multiple times a day but getting to them requires many clicks. I have too many bookmarks already to create bookmarks for each of these sites so I'm looking for a Chrome extension that will let me visit urls quickly. Perhaps with some sort of key word? Can anyone direct me to the Chrome extension that could help me to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm, have you taken a look at Redirect? I created the Chrome extension for almost exactly this purpose and it serves me well.

Here's a link to the Github repo: 
https://github.com/kritts/redirect/

And a link to the extension in the Chrome Web Store:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect/ndmlefihodnjkipamdighnjjmiddafai

If you have any feedback about it, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
goo.gl URL Shortener
```

May be this is the one that you need. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/googl-url-shortener/iblijlcdoidgdpfknkckljiocdbnlagk

Comment: I'm looking for something a little bit more long term that I could use on a day to day basis. For example, I visit a certain photo album 4-5 times a day and want a quick way to jump to that album rather than having to type the entire url in each time. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think this serves the purpose as you just need to enter the url of that album and Google URL Shortener will create a short url for the same. Then you can use it everytime.